# How to drive a linear MOSFET like IXTK22N100L?

Tags: analog, design

i am trying to simulate an electronic load. in that case i would like to employ a linear MOSFET IXTK22N100  which has Ciss= 7n for having a current at 150khz at output. but in the simulation i couldn’t make it stable and the current is not a pure sinewave at high frequency applications. i am thinking that maybe my op-Amp cannot supply an appropriate current to drive this kind of MOSFET at high frequency but i am not sure that is it true or not? should i use an gate driver stage or using specific gate driver IC between Op-amp and MOSFET? if yes which kind of IC or structure can help me?

[image]

Comment: LT1220 can only supply 26mA output current. Don't use a gate driver, as these are not meant for linear applications. You can add an output stage to your opamp to boost the current sourcing ability and decouple the 7nF gate capacitance from your opamp. [Linear Tech AN-18](http://www.linear.com/docs/4114) is relevant here.

Comment: @Oleksandr R.  thank you for your comment.
i studied that application note i am thinking to use LT1010. should i use Lt1010 between Lt1220 and Mosfet in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circuit is commonly used as a current sink and therefore is fundamentally valid.The input C of your linear fet is high and it could form a nasty pole with the Opamps output impedence giving you control system hassles like instability or poor transient response .Putting in some gate resistance in would be wise because the opamp could be unstable into such a big capacitance anyway.An emmiter follower is good because it divides the effective capacitance seen by the Opamp by the gain of the transistors.I havenot  applied this circuit or its variants on a expensive linear fet .I would guess that your proposed linear fet would give better stability and transient response than the cheaper more common and less suitable switching type powermosfet.I have used opamps on smaller powerfets in a previous life .I did not have to do too much to the basic circuit to get it stable .

Answer (score 0):

1. Lose R1 and feed the input signal into the opamp positive input.

   Put a resistor between the opamp output and the FET gate.  Maybe 1 kΩ.

   If that is not stable, then add a capacitor between the output of the opamp and the negative input.  Start with 22 pF or so and increase until the system is stable.  Use about 1.5x the lowest capacitance that appears cause stability by experimentation.

   This will have the side effect of slowing down the response of the system, but see where it's at with the capacitor.  Maybe it's good enough.  There are other more sophisticated ways to compensate such systems, but those are beyond the scope of a simple answer here.

Comment: @ Olin Lathro Thank you 
I did these kind of modifationbut it is still unstable when the input control signal has high frequency 150khz. i think i need to use a current booster too charge the gate source capacitance. may be the Oleksandr R. can help me, i studied to use that approach but it was not easy to me.